# oracle table saving issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am trying to insert some values into the `oracle` database table. but while Inserting I am getting error as

> Invalid Number

I don't know why.

Kindly let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue: `DELETE_FLAG CHAR(1 BYTE),`; if this is just going to hold `Y`/`N` consider instead using a `bool` field with `1`/`0`.

Comment: @JohnLBevan: let me try and check.

Comment: @JohnLBevan: yeah that worked

Comment: Deleted original comment as contained sensitive information.  Original comment with name changed: `CREATED_BY NUMBER(10),` / `<CREATED_BY>Ann Droid</CREATED_BY>`.  @Coder: NB: This name is also in your question and in your comment above; recommend you amend there also if this is sensitive.

Comment: @JohnLBevan: thanks for deleting it, yeah i will also remove that. As it is sensitive data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have CREATED_BY declared as a NUMBER(10)

The error was invalid number -- so to find the problem you check all the places the system expects a number.

Comment: yeah..silly me. that's was a stupid mistake from. that worked. thanks for pointing out